Problem with creating multiple threads to operate on different parts of vec
**Im having problems with creating multiple threads to operates on different parts of a vec. **
Im dealing with having to run processes on each element in long vectors.
I though it might be a good idea to create multiple thread and have each of them work on diffrent parts of the vector at the same time.
This is my current code to try to solve this issue:
`
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let test = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    let list_one = &test[0..test.len()/2]; 
    let list_two = &test[test.len()/2..test.len()];

    let task1= thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in list_one.iter() {
            sum_func(i);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    });

    let task2= thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in list_two.iter() {
            sum_func(i);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        }
    });
    task1.join().unwrap();
    task2.join().unwrap();
}  

`
I keep getting an error telling me that the borrowed value does not live long enough.
The exact error :
error[E0597]: `test` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:21
   |
5  |       let test = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   |           ---- binding `test` declared here
...
8  |       let list_two = &test[test.len()/2..test.len()];
   |                       ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 |       let task2= thread::spawn(move || {
   |  ________________-
18 | |         for i in list_two.iter() {
19 | |             println!("hi number {} from the spawned thread2!", i);
20 | |             thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
21 | |         }
22 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `test` is borrowed for `'static`
...
25 |   }
   |   - `test` dropped here while still borrowed

Does anyone know who i can resolve this issue or if there are any better solution to my problem.
Thank you!

Scoped threads are the answer.

Or rayon
